# Getting Undefined Variable Error in PHP

Tags: php

How can I get PHP variable value from one PHP block to another PHP block in same PHP page

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
$name=$school=$web=$location=$phone=$email=$comments="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['Full']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } 
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",trim($_POST['Full']))){
        $hasError = true;
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
    else {
        $name = secure_data($_POST['Full']);
    }
:
:
```

Between jquery and HTML code are there, then

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><label for="Full" class="label">Full Name<span class="required_star"> * </span></label></td>
    <td width="310" valign="top"><input type="text" name="Full" id="Full" value=""  maxlength="80" style="width:230px"/></td>
    <td width="159" class="status"><font color="#CC0000"><?php echo $nameErr;?></font></td>
</tr>
```

Getting Error -

> Notice: Undefined variable: nameErr in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\contact_us.php on line 232

Comment: initialize `$nameErr` the same way you are initializing the other variables

Comment: Or check that it exists before attempting to use it....

Comment: `$nameErr` is only set if `$_POST['submit']` is set and possibly not even then, which won't be true on the first load.

Comment: use `<td width="159" class="status"><font color="#CC0000"><?php if(isset($nameErr)){echo $nameErr;}?></font></td>` instead `<td width="159" class="status"><font color="#CC0000"><?php echo $nameErr;?></font></td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo isset($nameErr) ? $nameErr : 'No Error';?>
```